# How to use a thread member variable of a class c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'd like to have a thread variable as a class member like this:

```
class Example{
    public:
        void startTask();
    private:
        std::thread m_taskThread;
}
```

my questions are:

1. Assuming that the creation of this thread object will happen in `startTask()`, what is the scope of this thread object? Does it live till the `Example` class object gets destroyed like normal member variables? Or its scope is the scope of that particular method(`startTask()`)?
2. Where should I call `.join()` on the spawned thread if I want this thread to live as long as the `Example` object? In the destructor of `Example` class?
3. Some material(https://thispointer.com/c11-how-to-use-stdthread-as-a-member-variable-in-class/) online says I should create move-only class if I need to use std::thread as member variable, why is that?
4. Is it good to have a thread object as a member variable? Reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Assuming that the creation of this thread object will happen in
>   startTask(), what is the scope of this thread object? Does it live
>   till the Example class object gets destroyed like normal member
>   variables? Or its scope is the scope of that particular
>   method(startTask())?

The scope of the thread object is at the level of the Example object. But, the thread will not start running until you call startTask(). Do no confuse having a thread instance and having a running thread instance.

> Where should I call .join() on the spawned thread if I want this
>   thread to live as long as the Example object? In the destructor of
>   Example class?

Yes, you can call it at the destructor and it is safe.

> Some
>   material(https://thispointer.com/c11-how-to-use-stdthread-as-a-member-variable-in-class/)
>   online says I should create move-only class if I need to use
>   std::thread as member variable, why is that?

Because the std::thread is not copyable, but it is movable. So your example class cannot be copyable as well.

> Is it good to have a thread object as a member variable? Reasons?

Yes, why not. I see no problem with that. You create one class with the responsibility of managing a resource, that is a thread.